# The number of of Dyck paths that do not end at level $0$

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

A Dyck path of $2n$ steps is a path on a lattice from $(0,0)$ to $(2n, 0)$ with steps restricted to $(+1, +1)$ or $(+1, -1)$, with the extra condition that the path does not go below the $x$-axis.

It is well known that the number of such paths is the Catalan number $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$.

I wonder what is the number of such paths of length $(2n +m)$ which ends at $(2n+m, m)$ where $m >0$?

I looked into the literature of lattice paths but I have not seen any simple formulas for this.

Comment: I have usually seen Dyck paths explained either as paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n, n)$ using the steps $(+1, +0)$ and $(+0, +1)$ and restricted to not going below the diagonal $x=y$, or as paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(2n, 0)$ using the steps $(+1, +1)$ and $(+1, -1)$ and restricted to not going below the $x$ axis. Your explanation seems like a mix of the two, and I don't think your mix works.

Comment: @Arthur If you rotate the representation you just described counter clockwise by 145 degrees, you get the same one I described above. See this for example, this [one](https://math.mit.edu/~apost/courses/18.204-2016/18.204_Gabriella_Baracchini_final_paper.pdf)

Comment: I really don't think so. In particular because the only way to get from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2n)$ in $2n$ steps, using the steps you listed, is to use $2n$ copies of $(+1,+1)$. You have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you are right. It should ends at $(2n, 0)$. I fixed the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n+m,m)$, where each step is $(+1,+1)$ or $(+1,-1)$, and which never go below the $x$-axis, using the reflection principle.

There are $\binom{2n+m}{n}$ paths total, including the "bad" paths which touch the line $y=-1$ at some point. Given a bad path, $P$, define a new path, $P_\text{refl}$ as follows. Find the first point, where $P$ intersects the line $y=-1$, and vertically reflect every step after that point to get $P_{\text{refl}}$.

Since $P$ went from the line $y=-1$ up to the line $y=m$ at the end, the reflected path $P_\text{refl}$ will instead go from $y=-1$ down to $y=-m-2$. That is, $P_\text{refl}$ is a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2n+m,-m-2)$. Furthermore, you can show that this reflection map is a bijection from the set of bad paths to $(2n+m,m)$, to the set of all paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n+m,-m-2)$. It follows that the number of bad paths is
$$
\binom{2n+m}{n-1}.
$$
Therefore, the number of good paths is
$$
\binom{2n+m}{n}-\binom{2n+m}{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Excellent !.....